# "astro build" runs fine in dev mode, but when I try to deploy with GitHub Pages it crashes with Could not resolve component

Tags: github, deployment, astrojs

EDIT:
I solved the issue but I'm leaving it here for others:

The problem was that I had changed the folder name from "Cards" to "cards" at some point in order to be consistent, but it didn't update in GitHub, no matter how many times I committed. I changed it back and it worked.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I'm trying to build a simple static presentation website with Astro. Everything works fine in development, but when I try to deploy to GitHub pages or Render.com I get this error messages as it tries to build static entry points:

```
08:14:40 AM [content] No content directory found. Skipping type generation.
08:14:40 AM [build] output target: static
08:14:40 AM [build] Collecting build info...
08:14:40 AM [build] Completed in 149ms.
08:14:40 AM [build] Building static entrypoints...
Could not resolve "../components/cards/BlogCard.astro" from "src/pages/courses.astro"
file: /home/runner/work/cursuri-seo/cursuri-seo/src/pages/courses.astro
error   Could not resolve "../components/cards/BlogCard.astro" from "src/pages/courses.astro"
File:
/home/runner/work/cursuri-seo/cursuri-seo/src/pages/courses.astro
Stacktrace:
RollupError: Could not resolve "../components/cards/BlogCard.astro" from "         src/pages/courses.astro"
at error (file:///home/runner/work/cursuri-seo/cursuri-   seo/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2287:30)
at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///home/runner/work/cursuri-seo/cursuri-  seo/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24778:24)
at file:///home/runner/work/cursuri-seo/cursuri-seo/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-   entry.js:24740:26

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`
```

I really don't understand why the component would not resolve, as it works fine in development.

Here is the component:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AOHj.png)

And here is where it is called from:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI3Jq.png)

Actually, it is being called from other pages too, and sometimes the error message points to those. So it's always this BlogCard component that is causing the issue.

I tried to deploy to GitHub pages and I expected the build to work

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question, but do post the solution as an answer, not as an edit to the question. Stackoverflow has a very strict question / answer separation. That way others can also post answers (if there is more than one solution) and people can vote for answers.